# Auto Load More on scroll down is loading only first 2 pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have auto load more on page scroll down.
My jQuery/ajax is working but it is auto loading only first 2 pages on scroll down. There are more pages/records but it stuck after 2nd page loads.

I cannot understand the issue.
Somebody please help me out. My php and java code is given below

just played around with the same moving lines up and down but no use.

```php
<?php
    $pxe    =   $_GET['pname'];
    $sxe    =   $_GET['sname'];
?>

$(document).ready(function(){
        var is_ajaxed = false;
    function getresult(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            data:  {rowcount:$("#rowcount").val()},
            beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loader-icon').show();
            },
            complete: function(){
            $('#loader-icon').hide();
            },
            success: function(data){
            $("#faq-result").append(data);
            },
            error: function(){}             
       });
    }
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()-900) && is_ajaxed == false){
            if($(".pagenum").val() <= $(".total-page").val()) {
                var pagenum = parseInt($(".pagenum").val()) + 1;
                var pname = "<?php echo $pgianame; ?>";
                var sname = "<?php echo $stianame; ?>";
                getresult('sellers_forum_page_posts_getresult.php?page='+pagenum+'&pname='+pname+'&sname='+sname);
            is_ajaxed = true
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

`getresult.php`

```php
<?php
include('inc/db.php');

$perPage = 10;
$sql = "SELECT * from posts";
$allrows = $dba3->query($sql);
$allrowscount = mysqli_num_rows($allrows);
$pages  = ceil($allrowscount/$perPage);

$page = 1;
if(!empty($_GET["page"])) {
$page = $_GET["page"];
}
$start = ($page-1)*$perPage;
if($start < 0) $start = 0;

$query =  $sql." limit ".$start.",".$perPage; 
$faq = $dba3->query($query);
if(empty($_GET["rowcount"])) {
$_GET["rowcount"] = mysqli_num_rows($faq);
}
$output = '';
if(!empty($faq)) {
$output .= '<input hidden class="pagenum" value="'.$page.'" />';
$output .= '<input hidden class="total-page" value="'.$pages.'" />';
while ($row = $faq->fetch_assoc()) {
 $output .=  $row["ename"];
} }
print $output;
?>
```

no errors just loader image keeps moving

Comment: What's the value of `total-page` being output? Surely if you are using the row-count returned from your query to calculate the total number of pages, that will always be the number of rows per page because of your LIMIT clause? Also, don't you need to check the `:last` value of it, as you output it with each new block of rows?

Comment: `total-page` is returning `1`. im stuck here please help me out

Comment: You do this `select * from posts limit per page` then `pages = rowcount` where (effectively) `rowcount = select count(*) from posts limit per page`.  You need to set the total row count *before* you apply the limit.

Comment: @freedomn-m would you please set it up and post here i tried by myself but cannot.

Comment: You've changed the original question - please only add new information, not change the original question as it makes valid, existing answers no longer relevant.

Comment: This line `data:  {rowcount:$("#rowcount").val()},` sends the number or rows - what use is that? You want to send the current `page` which you need to increase each time

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry for the editing origional. As i have made 2 `inputs` there it is showing in one it show page 2 and total pages 3 when records are 21 and limit set to 10 per page. again if you will assist me like a full format that will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The key is to get the row count from the initial sql, before applying the limit, something like:

```
$perPage = 10;
$sql = "SELECT * from posts";
$allrows = $dba3->query($query);
$allrowscount = mysqli_num_rows($allrows);
$pages  = ceil($allrowscount/$perPage);

$page = 1;
if(!empty($_GET["page"])) {
$page = $_GET["page"];
}
$start = ($page-1)*$perPage;
if($start < 0) $start = 0;

$query =  $sql . " limit " . $start . "," . $perPage; 
$faq = $dba3->query($query);
```

Comment: please check i have updated the code in my question after your answer. It is echoing the 3 pages if you will print `$pages` But result is the same.

Answer (score -1):

You should add `async : false,` in your ajax request.

```
url: url,
async : false,
type: "GET",
data:  {rowcount:$("#rowcount").val()},
```

Your browser needs to wait for the response before the next request is sent.

Comment: `async : false,` did not helped me out.

Comment: Have you tried by changing `if($(".pagenum:last").val() <= $(".total-page").val()) {` to `if(parseInt($(".pagenum:last").val()) <= parseInt($(".total-page").val())) {` ?

Comment: Can you provide any url of your site for testing, where this issue is happening?

Comment: its still local. It loads the 2nd page and then only loading image keeps moving i dont know where is the issue. total records are 21 and it shows 20 the 21st record is on 3rd page. and even records will be more and more

Comment: Have you tried removing return false; after $("#faq-result").append(data); in success function. Try also by adding $('#loader-icon').hide(); after $("#faq-result").append(data);